# How do I modify a record in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

I'm a rails begginer and I was coding a simple app to train the language and other stuff.

In my app, I have three different scaffolds generated, one for **People**, one for **House Activities** and one last to link them together called **Assignments**. It's a many to many dependency situation.

So I was trying to calculate the total time a person would have to spend doing all the house activities assigned to them and store it inside the Person in an attribute called "time_allocated". So if I have two activities assigned to someone, it would return the sum of the duration of those activities.

After searching I discovered that creating an attribute with three dependencies is no good, but I don't know how to do it other way.

These are the models and the things that I tried to do:

**Person Model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :house_activities, through: :assignments
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

**House Activity Model**

```
class HouseActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :people, through: :assignments
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

**Assignment Model**

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :house_activity

  def self.time_allocation #fulltime
    Assignment.all.each do |assignment|
      if (assignment.person.time_allocation.present?)
        assignment.person.time_allocation += assignment.house_activity.duration
      else
        assignment.person.time_allocation = assignment.house_activity.duration
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to get the sum of the `duration`s for all of a Person's `house_activities`? It would be helpful if you would edit your question to include some example data and your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the sum of the `duration`s of all of a Person's `house_activities`. You can get this directly from the database using Rails' [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method:

```
person = Person.find(123)
puts person.house_activities.sum(:duration)
# => 500
```

Of course, you could create a helper method for this as well:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def total_activities_duration
    house_activities.sum(:duration)
  end
end

person = Person.find(123)
puts person.total_activities_duration
# => 500
```

I would advise against storing this sum in the database, because then you have to ensure its consistency (e.g. every time an Assignment is created, edited, or deleted, you have to ensure that the associated Person is updated with the new sum). You might think that calculating the sum anew every time will slow down your app, and it may at some time in the future when you have thousands of records, but there's no need to optimize this unless and until an actual performance problem arises.

Comment: Wow, It was so much easier than i thought. Thanks for the help and the advice!